# Numbers to brackets sequences

Tags: pattern

Find the rule between these numbers and their brackets sequences.

1 = not defined
2 = <>
3 = <<>>
4 = <><>
5 = <<<>>>
6 = <><<>>
7 = <<><>>
8 = <><><>
9 = <<>><<>>
10 = <><<<>>>
11 = <<<<>>>>
12 = <><><<>>
13 = <<><<>>>
14 = <><<><>>
15 = <<>><<<>>>
16 = <><><><>
17 = <<<><>>>
18 = <><<>><<>>
19 = <<><><>>
20 = <><><<<>>>
...

Note: Every number bigger than 1 can be written like this.

I got this puzzle from my friend.

Comment: Is it brainf**k.

Comment: i dunno why but its ... beautiful *.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@lois6b](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26960/lois6b) has already found out, numbers can be multiplied by juxtaposing their bracket representations: 6 = 2×3, so the bracket representation is the representation of 2 next the representation of 3, `<> <<>>`. The first factor is the smallest factor, usually a small prime.

Primes cannot be gerenated in that fashion, so there is a special rule for them: The `n`th prime is represented by `<n>`, that is the bracket representation of n enclosed in brackets.

Here's a small Python program that prints the list above:

```
rep = ["", ""]
primes = []

def smallfact(n):
    for p in primes:
        if n % p == 0:
            return p
    return 1

for n in range(2, 21):
    s = smallfact(n)

    if s == 1:
        primes.append(n)
        rep.append("<" + rep[len(primes)] + ">")

    else:
        rep.append(rep[s] + rep[n / s])

    print n, '=', rep[-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

answer: (update)

> The prime numbers are nth prime seems to be encoded as `<n>`, so 5, which is the 3rd prime number is `<<<>>>`  (thanks to M Oehm :* )
>  2 is `<n>` -> `<1>`  ->  `<>`
>
>  The even numbers are product of other numbers:
>  10 = `<><<<>>>` -> because  `<>`(2) * `<<<>>>` (5) = 10
>  20 = `<><><<<>>>` -> because `<><>` (4) * `<<<>>>` (5) = 20

Comment: 5 is the 3rd prime and the nth prime seems to be encoded as `<n>`, so 5 is `<<<>>>`.

Comment: @MOehm That seems an awful lot like the (rest of the) answer to me.

Comment: @MOehm you are right but you are not counting 1 as the first prime , arent you? can I add it to my answer?

Comment: @lois6b: 2 is the first prime and its representation is nothing (or undefined, the value of 1) enclosed in brackets.

Comment: oh right, ^^' can i add it and giving you credit?

Comment: This might be another clue: $2^n$ is $n$ copies of `<>`.

Comment: @lois6b: Of course, otherwise I wouldn't have commented it. (But I'm currently writing up an answer of my own, if you don't mind.)